# Ограничение количества символов в textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

Сделал textarea, в который посетители сайта могут оставлять комментарий, как сделать так, чтобы они не смогли оставить более 1000 символов?

Comment: [Пожалуй, пора добавить тэг `[jquery]` в игнор, ибо его клиентура...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength)

Comment: @karmadro4, тег maxlength поддерживается только HTML5, а тот, в свою очередь, мягко говоря, не всеми браузкрами...но вы это, конечно же знали.

Comment: @0xFFh, а страницу до поддержки браузеров доскроллить? Его не поддерживают только IE9- и IE Mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1000)
        this.value = this.value.substr(0, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Я реализовал со счётчиком, правильным... а то даже на плагине в минуса уходит

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxCount = 2000;

    $("#counter").html(maxCount);

    $("#review-text").keyup(function() {
    var revText = this.value.length;

        if (this.value.length > maxCount)
            {
            this.value = this.value.substr(0, maxCount);
            }
        var cnt = (maxCount - revText);
        if(cnt <= 0){$("#counter").html('0');}
        else {$("#counter").html(cnt);}

    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="box">
    <form method="" action="">
        <div>Ваше имя:</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="review-name"></div>
        <div>Ваш отзыв об этом товаре:</div>
        <div><textarea name="review-text" rows="7" id="review-text"></textarea></div>
        <div class="counter">Осталось символов: <span id="counter"></span></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

ну кнопку `submit` сами нарисуете...
может кто попроще может написать, ну у меня вот так...

Comment: правой кнопкой мыши. paste.

Answer (score 2):

Еще есть вот такой плагин: [Simplest Twitter-like dynamic character count for textareas and input fields](http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas/).

Comment: Спасибо, но ИМХО для такой задачи использовать плагин нет смысла. Плюс там просто количество символов уходит в минус, а мне нужно, чтобы более 1000 символов нельзя было ввести.

Answer (score 1):

Три способа реализации: **HTML5, JavaScript, JQuery**. Ограничение 10 символов.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea maxlength="10">HTML5</textarea><br/>
<textarea onkeyup="this.value=this.value.substring(0,10);">JavaScript</textarea><br/>
<textarea onkeyup="$(this).val($(this).val().slice(0,10));">JQuery</textarea><br/>
```