# Ограничение на количество символов в текстовом поле.

Tags: jquery

Подскажите есть input с текстом.Пользователь сам вводит в его информацию.Подскажите как сделать так что бы показывалось сколько сколько пользователю осталось ввести символов в поле.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @raptor96, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Что-то заголовок с телом вопроса расходятся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно [так попробовать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xsgkJ/).

Comment: `$('#cnt span')` можно было бы тоже закэшировать, но в целом хорошая реализация

Answer (score 1):

Может [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/124050/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-textarea) поможет. Там есть мой ответ про маленький плагин.